# MouseButton.LeftButton is incorrectly reporting as released during drag drop GiveFeedback

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

Not sure why this is occurring.  I'm subscribing to GiveFeedback when doing a drag drop.

Inside of this GiveFeedback I'm checking the state of the left mouse button.  If it's released I want to do "something" (not important).

The below always returns with "Mouse Button RELEASED".

My code:

```
private void GiveDragFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs args)
{
  var mouseArgs = new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0);

  if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse Button PRESSED");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse Button RELEASED");

  if (Mouse.PrimaryDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    _adorner_MouseMove(sender, new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0));
  else
    _adorner_MouseUp(sender, mouseArgs);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense.  If the left mouse button is released then drag+drop stops.  Your event handler would never be called.  You'll need to re-think this.

Comment: What doesn't make sense?  Ignore the last 4 lines.  I want to know why MouseButtonState is never "Pressed" while dragging.  It always returns RELEASED.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
 protected override void OnQueryContinueDrag(QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.KeyStates.HasFlag(DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton))
        {
             e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
        }
    }
```